# Using an asyncIterator inside a unit test never resolves with values

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, openai-api

I have a readable stream from chatGPT that I'm trying to assert on using an asyncIterator and then reading those values and asserting on them. The jest test runs fine but there is an error in my logic that is stopping it from resolving after each iteration.

What am I missing?

Thanks Jimi

```
var util = require("util");

describe("stream", () => {
  it("should work", async () => {
    let i = -1;
    const completionStream: ChatCompletionStreamParams = {
      toReadableStream: () => {
        const mockReadable = {
          async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            const encoder = new util.TextEncoder("utf-8");
            yield encoder.encode(
              JSON.stringify({
                id: "1",
                object: "text",
                created: 1629159835,
                model: "gpt4",
                choices: [
                  {
                    index: 0,
                    delta: { content: "Hello" },
                    finish_reason: null,
                  },
                ],
              })
            ).buffer;
            yield encoder.encode(
              JSON.stringify({
                id: "1",
                object: "text",
                created: 1629159835,
                model: "gpt4",
                choices: [
                  {
                    index: 0,
                    delta: { content: "there" },
                    finish_reason: null,
                  },
                ],
              })
            ).buffer;
            yield null;
          },
          getReader: () => {
            return {
              read: async () => {
                const result = await mockReadable[
                  Symbol.asyncIterator
                ]().next();
                i++;
                if (i >= 2) {
                  return Promise.resolve({ done: true, value: null });
                }
                return Promise.resolve({ done: false, value: result?.value });
              },
            };
          },
        };
        return mockReadable;
      },
    };

    const readable = completionStream.toReadableStream().getReader();

    while (true) {
      const { done, value } = await readable.read();
      expect(done).toBe(false); // assert here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the `while(true)` is running indefinitely. How are you stopping it?

Comment: if (done) break

Comment: It never gets there as it processes the same row all of the time.

Comment: Okay let me propose a way to test as per me. 1.Try to create a counter to keep track of the iterations.(just before while). 2. Check if done is true. If so break the loop. 3. Increment the counter and perform your assertions(as you're doing). After that call a function for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in `getReader` at the `mockReadable[Symbol.asyncIterator]()` part. It is called every time you call `readable.read()`, which creates a **fresh** async iterator from scratch, thus it keeps yielding "Hello" and never reaches "there".

You need to save the iterator and reuse it.

```js
getReader: () => {
  const iterator = mockReadable[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
  return {
    read: async () => {
      const result = await iterator.next();
      return result;
    }

    // in fact you can just re-expose `iterator.next` as `read` like
    // read: iterator.next.bind(iterator),
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining what I did wrong as well and providing  the solution.

Answer (score -1):

it will work file:

```
it("should work", async () => {
  let i = -1;
  const completionStream: ChatCompletionStreamParams = {
    toReadableStream: () => {
      const mockReadable = {
        async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
          const encoder = new util.TextEncoder("utf-8");
          yield encoder.encode(
            JSON.stringify({
              id: "1",
              object: "text",
              created: 1629159835,
              model: "gpt4",
              choices: [
                {
                  index: 0,
                  delta: { content: "Hello" },
                  finish_reason: null,
                },
              ],
            })
          ).buffer;
          yield encoder.encode(
            JSON.stringify({
              id: "1",
              object: "text",
              created: 1629159835,
              model: "gpt4",
              choices: [
                {
                  index: 0,
                  delta: { content: "there" },
                  finish_reason: null,
                },
              ],
            })
          ).buffer;
          yield null;
        },
        getReader: () => {
          return {
            read: async () => {
              const result = await mockReadable[
                Symbol.asyncIterator
              ]().next();
              i++;
              if (i >= 2) {
                return Promise.resolve({ done: true, value: null });
              }
              return Promise.resolve({ done: false, value: result?.value });
            },
          };
        },
      };
      return mockReadable;
    },
  };

  const readable = completionStream.toReadableStream().getReader();

  while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await readable.read();
    expect(done).toBe(false); // assert here

    if (done) {
      break; // exit the loop when done is true
    }
  }
});
```